# Could someone please explain OOP using SPORT examples?

Tags: oop, inheritance, programming-languages, polymorphism

Im new to OOP concepts (Abstraction, Encapsulation, Inheritance and Polymorphism).

Could someone please explain OOP using a SPORTS example such as Sport which can have subclasses (Football, Rugby, Cricket, Boxing, snooker, etc).

Also what would be the basic structure for a Athlete Management System.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: I suppose it's a little difficult to explain you a so wide argument as OOP in a single answer. try to be more specific. Ask different questions for the concepts you can't understand.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming ,what did you search before ?

Answer (score 4):

This is a pretty generic question, and not easy to answer precisely, but here are a few pointers, which should hopefully give you some ideas about Inheritance and Polymorphism at least.

- All sports (the concepts) are in fact, instances of `Sport` (the class). This means that the classes `Football`, `Boxing`, etc, all inherit from the class `Sport`.
- Things that can be done in `Sport`, can be done in any subclass of `Sport`, since it is in fact, a sport. For instance, if `Cheer()`, `Score()`, and `win()` are defined as methods in `Sport`, then each of the sub-classes can also perform these - that is inheritance!
- Each sport may however, have different ways of scoring. If so, they can override the method from `Sport`, and provide their own logic for this. They must, however, still comply with the definition of the method `Score()` set down in `Sport`, for them to be able to behave as a `Sport`. This is polymorphism!
- Cheering and winning may be the same concept in all sports, so they can just be inherited from `Sport`

A simple pseudo code example. This may be pretty stupid (and maybe not even technically correct in sports terms, but I hope you get the point! :))

```
public class Sport{

    public function score(){ 
        print("Scored!");
    }

    public function Win(){
        print("Won!");
    }

    public function Cheer(){
        print("Cheeeeeeeeer!!!");
    }
}

public class Soccer Inherits Sport{
    public override function score(){
        print("One goal!");
    }
}

public class Boxing Inherits Sport{
    public override function score(){
        print("Knockout!");
    }
}


// Using the classes:
Sport generalSport = new Sport(); // generalSport is just a non-specific sport
Sport soccerSport = new Soccer(); // soccerSport is a Soccer, but also a Sport!
Sport boxingSport = new Boxing(); // boxingSport is a Boxing, but also a Sport!

generalSport.Win(); // This should output: "Won!" (from Sport)
soccerSport.Win(); // ... "Cheeeeeeeeer!!!" (inherited from Sport)
boxingSport.Cheer() // ... "Cheeeeeeeeer!!!" (inherited from Sport)

generalSport.score(); // "Scored!"
soccerSport.score(); // "One Goal", since it was overridden in Soccer
boxingSport.score() // "Knockout!", since overridden in Boxing
```

Hint: Just think of what things "are" in real life. If X inherits Y, X may be defined as an X specifically, but it is still a Y too, and can be treated as such (only with the possibility of adding a few extra properties).